# How to copy files before user delete them - Android

Tags: android

i'm a newbie. I'm making an application that works as an Recycle Bin. And i have a problem need help.

- I use android File Observer methods then i am getting notified after file deletion, then i copy it with path into my folder. **But new file in folder is empty**.

This is my code File Observer:

```
public void startWatching() {
    if (mObservers != null) return;

    mObservers = new ArrayList<SingleFileObserver>();
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    stack.push(mPath);

    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        String parent = stack.pop();
        mObservers.add(new SingleFileObserver(parent, mMask));
        File path = new File(parent);
        File[] files = path.listFiles();
        if (null == files) continue;
        for (File f : files)
        {
            if (f.isDirectory() && !f.getName().equals(".") && !f.getName().equals("..")) {
                stack.push(f.getPath());
            }
        }
    }

    for (SingleFileObserver sfo : mObservers) {
        sfo.startWatching();
    }
}

@Override
public void stopWatching() {
    if (mObservers == null) return;

    for (SingleFileObserver sfo : mObservers) {
        sfo.stopWatching();
    }
    mObservers.clear();
    mObservers = null;
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
    switch (event)
    {
        case FileObserver.ACCESS:
            Log.d("RecursiveFileObserver", "ACCESS: " + path);
            break;
        case FileObserver.ATTRIB:
            Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "ATTRIB: " + path);
            break;
        case FileObserver.CLOSE_NOWRITE:
            Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "CLOSE_NOWRITE: " + path);
            break;
        case FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE:
            Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "CLOSE_WRITE: " + path);
            break;
        case FileObserver.CREATE:
            Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "CREATE: " + path);
            break;
        case FileObserver.DELETE:
            Log.e("Save:", "Save file user delete");

            File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + ConstantUtils.FOLDER_RESTORE);
            if (!dir.exists()){
                dir.mkdir();

            }
            File inputFile = new File(path);
            String  str = String.valueOf(inputFile);
            if (!str.isEmpty()){
                String [] result =  str.split("/");
                int i = result.length;
                if (i > 4) {
                    String inputPath = result[i - 1];
                    File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + ConstantUtils.FOLDER_RESTORE + File.separator + inputPath);
                    String str1 = String.valueOf(inputFile);
                    String str2 = String.valueOf(outputFile);
                    if (str1.compareTo(str2) != 0){
                        ZipHelper.copyFileToFolder(inputFile, outputFile);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case FileObserver.DELETE_SELF:
            Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "DELETE_SELF: " + path);
            break;
        case FileObserver.MODIFY:
            Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "MODIFY: " + path);
            break;
        case FileObserver.MOVE_SELF:
            Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "MOVE_SELF: " + path);
            break;
        case FileObserver.MOVED_FROM:
            Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "MOVED_FROM: " + path);
            break;
        case FileObserver.MOVED_TO:
            Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "MOVED_TO: " + path);
            break;
        case FileObserver.OPEN:
            Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "OPEN: " + path);
            break;
        default:
            Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "DEFAULT(" + event + "): " + path);
            break;
    }
}
```

Please tell me how can i do it. Sorry for my English not good. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**FileObserver.DELETE** is triggered *after* the file is deleted which is why you can not copy it anymore. Apparently, there is no event in the FileObserver which tells you when a file is about to be deleted.

One very stupid approach might be to copy all files inside **mPath** initially to some cache directory, and then monitor for **FileObserver.DELETE**. You can then flag deleted files inside your database, but still allow the user to revert his deletion by just copying your cached file back into the directory.

This might be fine if there are only a handful of files, but certainly not when the directory is fairly large.

Comment: Thank for your help. But i don't want like that.

Comment: @TuNguyen Any solution you find till yet ?